# populate a hidden field on hitting submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form that has a hidden field. Upon hitting submit, I want the hidden field to be populated with the value entered in another field before it gets to form validation.Is there a way I can do that in Javascript?

HTML code:

```
<form>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="retype-email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1r8sunh/

Comment: Yes, just assign to the field's `.value`. What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: and how you plan to re-enter the email?

Comment: Is the purpose of this to hide the value of the hidden field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the HTML you posted, this should work:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    $('[name="retype-email"]').val($('[name="email"]').val());
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1bdgvyt/)

Pure JS option:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(){
    document.querySelector('[name="retype-email"]').value =  document.querySelector('[name="email"]').value;
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcrh70da/)

You will probably want to use ids or classes to select the elements. The above JS will probably conflict with other elements - change accordingly.